# Reading a file in reverse over order on python

Tags: python, file, reverse

```
import os.path
try:
    file1=input("Enter input file: ")
    infile=open(filename1,"r")
    file2=input("Enter output file: ")
    while os.path.isfile(file2):
        file2=input("File Exists! Enter new name for output file: ")
    ofile=open(file2, "w")
    content=infile.read()
    newcontent=content.reverse()
    ofile.write(newcontent)    

except IOError:
    print("Error")

else:
    infile.close()
    ofile.close()
```

Am I on the right track with this code? I can't seem to find a method to reverse the lines in the input file for the output file.

Input ex.

```
cat dog house animal

plant rose tiger tree

zebra fall winter donkey
```

Output ex.

```
zebra fall winter donkey

plant rose tiger tree

cat dog house animal
```

Comment: `reverse()` is an _in-place_ operation - which means it won't return the reversed list, it will modify the list in-place that is, it will reverse the list, but won't return anything. In Python, any method that does not have an explicit return value returns `None`, so this line: `newcontent=content.reverse()` is going to reverse `content`, but set `newcontent` to `None`.

Comment: You can read any file in reverse order, BUT, if your file is large this does not make sense !

Comment: @SivaCn: there is `tac` command in gnu coreutils that does exactly that. BSD `tail` command supports `-r` option.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the lines, in a reversed order. Here is a couple of ways.

Using `range`:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
for i in range(len(l)-1,-1, -1):
     print l[i]
```

The slice notation:

```
for i in l[::-1]:
    print i
```

Or, just use the built-in `reversed` function:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
for i in reversed(lines):
    newcontent.append(i)
```

Comment: `range(0, len(lines), -1)` should be `range(len(lines)-1, -1, -1)`.

Comment: In Python to reverse over a list, the common paradigm is to use `for i in lines[::-1]` instead of the `range` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import os.path
try:
  file1=raw_input("Enter input file: ") #raw input for python 2.X or input for python3 should work
  infile=open(file1,"r").readlines() #read file as list
  file2=raw_input("Enter output file: ")
  while os.path.isfile(file2):
    file2=raw_input("File Exists! Enter new name for output file: ")
  ofile=open(file2, "w")
  ofile.writelines(infile[::-1])#infile is a list, this will reverse it
  ofile.close()
except IOError:
  print("Error")
```

Comment: Note the raw_input function instead of the input function for full filenames.

Comment: OP might be on Python 3, where `input` is just like `raw_input`; you might want to add a comment to that effect.

Comment: O yea its definately using python3 the way he/she is using print

Comment: Strictly speaking; the print function was available in 2.6 as a future import: `from __future__ import print_function`